# Syntax error in sql statement?

Tags: mysql

I am getting a syntax error in the following lines. I am not familiar with mysql so any pointers will be helpfull

```
 ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO order(status,ordered_on,total_price,user_id) "
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1,"pending");
        ps.setTimestamp(2,date);
        ps.setDouble(3,total_price);
        ps.setInt(4,ID);
```

The error was 
`MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(status,ordered_on,total_price,user_id)  VALUES('pending','2017-03-22 04:08' at line 1`

Comment: Try removing the concatenation in the query to start. If that doesn't work try inserting just status (remove rest of vars to simplify things)

Comment: you have two spaces between ")  VALUES" and no space after values

Comment: `order` is a reserved word. Enclose it in "\`" if you are referring to a table with the same name like `\`order\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problemis that `order` is a reserved keyword for mysql ; so you have two solutions at your disposal
**1 :** if you are required some raison to use that work in case you case use  backtick escapes `order`
**2 :**  you can use plural for the tables name like orders

```
    ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `order`(status,ordered_on,total_price,user_id) "
            + " VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1,"pending");
    ps.setTimestamp(2,date);
    ps.setDouble(3,total_price);
    ps.setInt(4,ID);
```

This is q link to the mysal [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)